# Delphi TImageList bitmaps spontaneously convert themselves from color to black & white

Tags: delphi, delphi-4

I have an issue where the 16x16 bitmaps in an imagelist get corrupted and are displayed as monochrome black and white images.  This tends to happen between sessions in the IDE, so that after saving the project to disk, exiting the IDE, and opening up the project once again, lo and behold **the images have transformed!**  This requires rebuilding the imagelist and is very annoying.  A before and after example image is attached.

[image: Before and After Images]

This project is being developed (and shuttled between) WindowsXP and Windows 7 x64 using Delphi 4, which is installed on both operating systems.  The problem occurs rarely in XP and frequently in Windows 7.  Does anyone have a clue as to what is going on here?

Comment: FWIW I don't think it's a good idea to store images in a dfm file. They are much better linked as resources and the image list built at runtime.

Comment: It's possible that a third party library is message with things by registering a property editor, for example (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q576315). The safest bet is probably moving the lists out of the DFM which what David is suggesting.

Comment: I remember that those ancient Delphis had problems with image lists. I can't remember the details. Windows and video drivers were implicated.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan IIRC the Windows problems were to do with ComCtl32.dll deployment. That shouldn't be an issue here because these problems are design time ones and not at run time. I seem to also remember seeing something about video drivers.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan.  Just out of curiosity, since I am relatively new to the site and learning how to use it, why was the tag TImageList removed from the question?

Comment: Because we want tags for mainstream things. Not for every distinct component in vcl.